# Error in TCL Script

Tags: tcl

i have return a command to invoke my RTL compiler (Cadence Tool)using tcl script line

```
puts [exec rc -f script.g ]
```

i am getting error like abort child process. while if write it directly on my console the to invoke the tool $-rc -f script.g it is getting perfectly exectuded.

Comment: What is the exit code? Does this process write to stdout?

Comment: What _exactly_ is the error message?

Comment: Compiler tool fails to invoke and returning error: Child process aborted

Answer (score 0):

`exec` returns an error condition if:

- the exec'ed command returns with a non-zero status
- or it prints to stderr

Do this

```
if {[catch {exec rc -f script.g} output] == 0} {
    # normal exit status
    puts $output
} elseif {$errorCode eq NONE} {
    # normal exit status, but some output to stderr (contained in $output)
    puts $output
} else {
    # some error condition.
    # see http://wiki.tcl.tk/1039 for ways to handle
    puts "some error occurred: $errorCode"
}
```

Comment: A better fix might be to just redirect standard error. Hard to tell without knowing the actual failure mode.